# How to start camelcontext in osgi plugin project?

Tags: osgi, apache-camel

I have problems getting my Camel route to work inside a OSGI(Equinox)-Bundle respectively a Plug-In Project.

Route looks like:

```
public class Example2Routes extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        this.from("cxf:http://localhost:8080/exampleWS?wsdlURL=META-INF/exampleWS.wsdl&dataFormat=PAYLOAD").to("stream:out");
    }
}
```

My Test class that should start the Camel context:

```
public class Test {
    public static void run() throws Exception {

        DefaultCamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.addRoutes(new Example2Routes());
        camelContext.start();
            }
    }
```

The bundle is started within Eclipse with a OSGI Framework Run configuration.

Console:

```
osgi> 19:53:17.712  DEBUG  org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils:140     Using org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger for logging.
19:53:17.728  INFO   org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFActivator:88        Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf-transport (64) [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.CamelTransportFactory]
19:53:17.743  INFO   org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:84        Camel activator starting
19:53:17.743  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: InvokerInf
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.eclipse.osgi.services
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.eclipse.equinox.util
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: InvokerImpl
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: ch.qos.logback.core
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: ch.qos.logback.classic
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: wsdl4j
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.commons.logging
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: com.springsource.javax.activation
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: javax.mail
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.ws.xmlschema.core
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.cxf.bundle
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.springframework.transaction
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.camel.camel-cxf
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/cxf in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/cxfbean in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf
19:53:17.760  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/cxfrs in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.neethi
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: slf4j.api
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: com.springsource.org.apache.xml.resolver
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: javax.ws.rs.javax.ws.rs-api
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.camel.camel-spring
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/spring-event in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-spring
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:143       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/language/spel in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-spring
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.springframework.beans
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.commons.codec
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: target
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: log4j
19:53:17.775  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.springframework.core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.springframework.expression
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.eclipse.equinox.ds
19:53:17.791  INFO   org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:87        Camel activator started
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/bean in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/browse in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/class in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/dataset in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/direct in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/direct-vm in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/file in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/language in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/log in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/mock in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/properties in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/ref in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/seda in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/stub in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/test in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/timer in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/validator in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/vm in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/xslt in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:143       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/language/bean in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:143       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/language/constant in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:143       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/language/file in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:143       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/language/header in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:143       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/language/property in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:143       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/language/ref in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:143       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/language/simple in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:143       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/language/tokenize in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.791  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:143       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/language/xpath in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core
19:53:17.807  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.camel.camel-cxf-transport
19:53:17.807  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.springframework.context
19:53:17.807  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: CamelOSGIExample
19:53:17.807  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.eclipse.osgi
```

But now how to "start" the CamelContext? Without osgi, as a standard java application, the example worked; but there I had a main method with the camel context in it.

I tried a Activator to start the camel context with:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext arg0) throws Exception {

         Test.run();

                }
    }
```

But this caused Errors like

```
Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://http://localhost:8081/exampleWS?dataFormat=PAYLOAD&wsdlURL=META-INF%2FexampleWS.wsdl due to: No component found with scheme: cxf
```

although Console says:

```
20:13:04.319  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.ws.xmlschema.core
20:13:04.319  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.cxf.bundle
20:13:04.319  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.springframework.transaction
20:13:04.319  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:97        Bundle started: org.apache.camel.camel-cxf
20:13:04.319  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/cxf in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf
20:13:04.319  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/cxfbean in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf
20:13:04.319  DEBUG  org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator:128       Found entry: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/cxfrs in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf
```

Maybe the problem with Test.run() in the Activator occurs because the run method is called before all needed bundles/components are started?
But how to start the camel context otherwise?

**Update 1**

Changed to OsgiDefaultCamelContext. Did some imports. Now I'm getting:

```
The bundle "org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.2.0 [119]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.apache.http; version="4.2.0"
```

&

```
 The bundle "CamelOSGIExample_1.0.0.qualifier [120]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.apache.http.nio.conn; version="4.0.0.beta3"
```

But can't find this bundles..

**Update 2:**

Cause of

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.conn.ClientAsyncConnectionManager
```

I downloaded [httpasyncclient-osgi-4.0-beta3.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/httpcomponents/httpasyncclient-osgi/4.0-beta3/httpasyncclient-osgi-4.0-beta3.jar) and added *org.apache.http.nio.conn* to imports.

After that I got the problem, that the previous bundle needs e.g. *org.apache.http.client* or *org.apache.http.auth*.
So I downloaded *httpclient-osgi-4.2.1.jar* and *httpclient-osgi-4.2.2.jar* (cause some imports were neede with version 4.2.1 and some with 4.2.2), that contains the needed classes. But despite adding this bundles to the lunch config, I get

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in siServer.Activator.start() of bundle CamleOSGIExample.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/conn/ClientAsyncConnectionManager
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.conn.ClientAsyncConnectionManager
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
...
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/conn/ClientAsyncConnectionManager
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.conn.ClientAsyncConnectionManager
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
```

I don't understand this exception, cause I added *org.apache.http.nio.conn* to imports.

Searched for bundle that needs *org.apache.http.nio.conn* and found cxf-2.7.3.jar. But I think using the cfx-component of camel I also need this bundle..

Comment: You need to install these bundles that the imports requires. You can use advanced search on maven central to find the JAR that has the packages: http://search.maven.org/

Comment: Btw if you use Apache Karaf / ServiceMix, then its much easier to deploy and use Camel in that container, using features and either a spring-dm or blueprint xml file to bootstrap your application. Then you do not need to fiddle with OSGi Activator and whatnot.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't my decision.

Comment: See the features.xml file of Apache Camel, and you can see all the needed osgi bundles camel-cxf etc needs - its a lot. http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/karaf/apache-camel/2.10.3/apache-camel-2.10.3-features.xml

Comment: wow. is there a easy way to get them?

Comment: No OSGi kinda lacks a super-bundle or whatever to make installing easier. And hence why Karaf had to make up its features to solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an OsgiDefaultCamelContext when you use OSGi. This class should be in camel-core-osgi.

Comment: Hmm, also getting some errors. Do I need to call Test.run() from the Activator start() method?

Comment: Mr.Ibsen, how can you install camel-core-osgi feature in karaf 4?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it why lazy instantiation. If a bundle's start policy is set to 'lazy', it will only load classes and start when one of its classes are loaded by another bundle.
http://www.osgi.org/Design/LazyStart